# When does surjectivity imply injectivity?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite sets, such that $|A| = |B|$. If I define a function $f: A \to B$ which is surjective, does that imply that $f$ is injective? I feel like I have been told this in  some class, and intuitively it makes sense. But I cannot find any resources that confirm this.

Comment: It's a consequence of the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If it wasn't injective, there would be $a_1\ne a_2$ with the same image $b_0$, and then $|A|\ge |B|+1$ would hold, as we can choose at least one preimage for each $b$ and at least two for $b_0$, all different.

Answer (score 1):

For finite sets it indeed holds. Let $n = |A| = |B|$. If it was true that for some $x,y\in A$ we have $x\neq y$, but $f(x) = f(y)$, we would be left with only $n-2$ elements of $A$ ( that is $A$/{$x,y$} ) and with $n-1$ elements of $B$ ( that is $B$/{$f(x)$} = $B$/{$f$($y$)} ) they need to go to, so it would be impossible for $f$ to be surjective.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are finite and $|A| = |B|$ then means that $A$ and $B$ have some finite number, call it $n$, elements.

If $f:A\to B$ is surjerctive then if $x \in B$ then there is a $y$ so that $f(x) =y$.  If we remove $x$ from $B$ to get $B' = B\setminus \{x\}$ and if we remove $y$ from $A$ to get $A' = A\setminus\{x\}$. ANd $A'$ and $B'$ both have $n-1$ elements.

If we take $z \in B'$ then there is a $w \in A$ so that $f(w) = z$.  But $w \ne x$ because $f(x) = y \ne z$.  SO $w \in A'$.  We repeat the procedure all over again.

After we do this $n$ times we will end up going through all the elements of each set and *demonstrating* that each of the element of $A$ goes to a different element of $B$.

So $f$ is injective.

Two things to note.  One, that sets be finite is absolutely *essential*.  We *needed* the process to end.

But another is that this is sound and complete but complete unrigorous and informal.  At this point, I think most mathematicians would tsk-tsk, explain the necessary virtues of rigour and set you on the rigorous pathway of righteousness.

I'm going to take a slightly different stance and say that the purpose of rigor is to define things coherently.

The very first statement I made that wasn't rigorous was when I said "$A$ and $B$ both have $n$ elements". What does that mean and how do we know if something as $n$ elements?  If you had a plate of fish and said you had $5$ fish what does that mean and how do you know?  Well,  you'd just *count* them! Right.

And that *really* is what all the complicated definition of "Finite means there is a bijection between the set $\mathbb N_n = \{1,...,n\}$ for some $j$ and the set $A$... " all means.  It means, nothing more or less than "you can count the elements and there are $n$ elements".  YOu count *by* make the bijection.

And a *rigorous* proof is just a matter of making the above argument in terms of that definition "there are $n$ elements".